# How do you self reject an app with the new Itunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

So I'm not a big fan of change and the new itunes connect is making me unhappy.  I just uploaded an app binary and realized there is an issue I need to fix before Apple spends another 2 weeks reviewing it.  In the old days, I could just reject the binary, but I am not seeing that as an option now.  My app exists in the Pre-Release section, but I cannot figure out where to go to remove it.  Where do I go and how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no rejecting of pre-release apps.  You must change the build number and resubmit.  This is slightly different than how testflight used to do things where it would automatically increment the build each time you uploaded a binary.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.. I solve it by rejecting the app from iTunes connect application in my iPhone then u should delete the build from iTunes connect. Finally change app build number from XCode and iTunes then submit.

that's weird problem ,I hope they fix it soon.